# Python Script not getting most recent mail from outlook

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I have a python script that fetches recent mail from my inbox, it works fine but the problem is that it fetches an old mail as the most recent email.

I have synchronized my Outlook Application and it's now displaying all my recent emails as well but the python script keep on fetching an old mail prior to the synchronization.

I have also uninstalled the Outlook Application and downloaded new one from microsoft store, yet the script is showing the same old mail. I uninstalled pywin32, hoping to make a new connection to the Outlook Application, yet no positive result.

Here is my python script:

```
import win32com.client #pip install pywin32 if not installed

# Connect to Outlook by MAPI
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
body_content = message.body
sender = message.sender
subject = message.Subject
date = message.senton.date()
time = message.senton.time()
attachments = message.Attachments
print(body_content)
```

Is the problem from my script? How can I make this script to synchronize with my Outlook Application?

Comment: I think this is probably because Items collection is not sorted in any particular order until you explicitly call `Items.sort()`. Also, if you could post the output after calling `print(messages)`, that'd be helpful for us to provide you with suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I added Items.sort() and it worked!

This is how I did it after reading @Devanshu's comment

```
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
```

I called the sort method before getting the item.

Comment: When I try that I get the following error when the code try to get the e-mail : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetFirst'